# How does compiling circular dependencies work?

Tags: compiler-construction, circular-dependency

I've made the example in Java but I think (not tested) that it works in other (all?) languages.

You have 2 files. First, `M.java`:

```
public class MType {
    XType x;
    MType() {x = null;}
}
```

Second, another file  (in the same directory), `XType.java`:

```
public class XType {
   MType m;
   public XType(MType m) {this.m = m;}
}
```

Ok it's bad programming, but if you run `javac XType` it compiles: compiles even `MType` because `XType` needs it. But ... `MType` needs `XType` ... how does that work? How does the compiler know what is happening?

I would like to know how the compiler (javac or any other compilers you know) manages that situation, not how to avoid it.

I'm asking because I'm writing a precompiler and I would like to manage that situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to take a 2-pass, or [multi-pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler) approach:

> Languages like Java require a multi-pass compiler since the definition of x would not be required to come before the use:

```
public class Example {  
public static void main(String [] args) {
    assert(x==0);           
    x++;
    assert(x==1);
}
static int x=0;
}
```

There are various approaches, for example you could do the following:

The first pass could look for all variable declarations, the second for method declarations, etc. until the last pass uses all this information to compile the final code.

Comment: So when it compiles the second file the compiler already knows what the first is?

Comment: @Fabio - Each pass of the compiler processes all the files gathering the information needed for the next pass.

Answer (score 4):

The first file doesn't need to know anything about XType except that it is a type, and similarly for MType in the second file. Also, in Java, all objects are effectively the same size (because everything is accessed through references), so the size of the object is not needed. This is not so in other languages - your code as it stands would not compile in C++, for example (language syntax apart).

Comment: but if use a method of XType? It must know methods of Xtype.. no?

Comment: also, I'm not sure what you mean by "all objects are effectively the same size".

Comment: He is referring to the fact that (for example) `m` holds a reference, and all references have the same size.  But that's not the only information that is required about a type.  It is also necessary to know its members and lots of information about its super-type hierarchy.