# How can Object have a method (toString) that returns a String when String itself extends Object?

Tags: java

How can the Object class be aware of String until String has been compiled? String can't be compiled until Object is since it extends Object.

Is there an actual reason this is possible or is it just because it's built into the language? (JVM magic)

Comment: Please explain _When the Object class is parsed String doesn't exist_.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032874/how-does-compiling-circular-dependencies-work

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks, that explained it perfectly

Comment: voting to reopen to close as a duplicate of the proposed in [c54084525](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136469/how-can-object-have-a-method-tostring-that-returns-a-string-when-string-itself#comment54084525_33136469) instead. Moderators refused to handle this themselves.